# D Programming: How would I read 64 bit integer from file?

Tags: d

Hex looks like this <<"0000000000005205">>. I want it to return 0x5205 instead of reading it as 383368918279913472. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's big-endian. Use [`bigEndianToNative`](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#bigEndianToNative) from std.bitmanip.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#parse

```cs
auto myInt = parse!ulong(textFromFile, 16);
```

Comment: that's only when reading from a text encoding the number in hex not reading raw byte streams